# bash: error when counting number of files and comparing

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripts. I would like to compare the number of files I have in another directory using `ls`. And then I need to compare the number of files there with a variable I have.

```
if [ (cd reports_dir/ && ls) | wc  -gt $MAXIMUM_REPORTS ]; then
    echo hello
fi
```

This code gives the errors:

```
./monitor.sh: line 70: syntax error near unexpected token `cd'
./monitor.sh: line 70: `    if [(cd reports_dir/ && ls) | wc  -gt $MAXIMUM_REPORTS]; then'
```

I have idea why `cd` is unexpected. The command `(cd reports_dir/ && ls) | wc` works when I run it in the terminal.

This command would be running in a `while` loop so it will be called repeatedly. Thus I cannot actually cd into the directory as it attempts to `cd` more than once, resulting in an error.

Comment: what does  "wc  -gt $MAXIMUM_REPORTS"  do ? .....

Comment: the whole part of that command is (cd reports_dir/ && ls) | wc . It goes to that directory and prints the number of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command fails because you need to use [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) syntax, otherwise it expects a value.

As you noted, you shouldn't be changing directory with `cd` - you can use the directory as an argument to `ls`. Also `wc` command by default returns a count for the number of lines, words, and bytes and in your expression you need only the first one, so you should add an argument `wc -l`.

Other than that you need to decide if you want to include hidden files and use `ls -A <dir> | wc -l`. `-A` makes `ls` to print all files including hidden ones, but excluding default `.` and `..`.

Finally use the [double parentheses](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html) for [arithmetical comparison](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/arithmetic_expressions.shtml) in the condition clause:

```
if (( $(ls -A reports_dir | wc -l) > $MAXIMUM_REPORTS )); then
    echo hello, but read the comment below
fi
```

Having said that, the above recipe will work in majority of cases, however [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35237252/2947502) contains **the** correct solution.

Comment: I like this answer more as it is easier to understand and works for most cases.

Comment: I am using this script within another bunch of scripts so I just looked the the "hello" output to check if it's working. I didn't know that worked too. Thanks.

Comment: Do not use `ls` output for anything. `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing `ls` output with code are broken. Globs are much more simple AND correct.
Read [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @techraf Indeed. Your comments regarding the answer are fine. I just don't like the fact that this answer is the accepted answer, since people with the same problem tend to not read the entire thing and just use the bad code from the answer which has the green checkmark. If your answer is about giving a reference to the correct answer, my logic says that you should give this answer an up-vote instead.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein I don't like it either. :)

Comment: I think that when it comes to merely _counting_ files, the `ls` / `wc -l` combo is fine, and certainly easier to write.
(The only known pitfall - [behavior of `ls -A` on HP-UX](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) - is probably not a real-world concern to many, and, assuming `ls -a` works predictably everywhere, it can be worked around.)
That said, parsing `ls` output for _filenames_ should be avoided, and it's advisable to form a habit of not relying on `ls` and working with globs instead.

Answer (score 5):

[techraf's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35237259/45375) explains the problem with the OP's approach and offers an effective solution based on `ls`.

Since only *counting* of files is required in this case, use of `ls ... | wc -l` should work as expected; however, it is ***generally* preferable to work with *pathname expansion* (globbing) in Bash**:

- Globbing can safely be used to collect filenames in an array and to drive a `for` loop.

  - You can do neither robustly with `$(ls ...)` - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs
- Globbing, since it is a Bash-internal feature, is more efficient than using `ls`, which is an external utility.

The following solutions demonstrates the use of *pathname expansion* (globbing) as an alternative to `ls`:

<sup>Note: By default, globbing does not include *hidden* files; set `shopt -s dotglob` (temporarily) to include them.</sup>

```
if (( $(shopt -s nullglob; set -- reports_dir/*; echo $#) > $MAXIMUM_REPORTS )); then
    echo hello
fi
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` ensures that nothing is returned in case the directory is empty.
- `set -- reports_dir/*` sets the positional parameters (`$1`, ...) to the result of the pathname expansion.
- `$#` returns the count of set parameters, which in this case reflects the count of files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one , cd into a given directory, get count compare with $MAXIMUM_REPORTS and take it from there. passes both test cases.

```
 [za-  tools]$ MAXIMUM_REPORTS=2; 
     mydir=font-awesome-4.3.0/ ; 
     if [[ $(cd $mydir && ls -1 $@ | wc -l)  -gt $MAXIMUM_REPORTS ]]; then 
        echo "hello" ;
     else echo "byeee" ; fi
```

Outputs:
    hello

```
[za tools]$ MAXIMUM_REPORTS=18;
  mydir=font-awesome-4.3.0/ ;
  if [[ $(cd $mydir && ls -1 $@ | wc -l)  -gt $MAXIMUM_REPORTS ]]; then 
     echo "hello" ; 
  else echo "byeee" ; 
fi
```

outputs:
    byeee

OR:

```
file_count=$(ls $mydir 2>/dev/null | wc -l) ; 
if [ $file_count -gt $MAXIMUM_REPORTS ]; then echo "hello" ; else echo "byee" ; fi
```

Simulate `wc -l with sed`

```
count=$(ls $mydir 2>/dev/null | sed -n '$=' ) ;
if [ $count -gt $MAXIMUM_REPORTS ]; then echo "$count greater then  $MAXIMUM_REPORTS" ; 
else echo "$count less $MAXIMUM_REPORTS" ; fi
```